Is it reasonable to list PhD funding as grant money for an industry CV?
A colleague passed me their CV which they have used for applications to non-academic positions. In it they have a short sentence/profile that states that have X publications, Y citations and $Z in grants.
In calculating what the value for Z should be, they include the funding provided for their PhD.
My question is, is this a reasonable practice?
In the UK science PhDs are typically funded by a Science and Technology Facilities Council (STFC) studentship. The studentship covers university fees, pays a stipend, and offers some extra cash for e.g. travel to conferences. The studentships are competitively awarded.
I can see the argument for, which is that this is funding which has been competitively awarded by a funding body. Other PhDs may e.g. self-fund or be employed directly by a supervisor's grant money.
The argument against is that the funding is not awarded directly to the applicant, but travels via a university. It is effectively just a way of listing your salary + benefits during your PhD. To me this seems somewhat different to money awarded via an independent research grant.
For academic applications, I would not list PhD funding as "grants", but it may go under a (e.g.) "scholarships" section.
For non-academic applications, is it reasonable to roll all the money under a single Z value in this way?

I doubt that most non-academic employers care about your grant money at all. Most likely, the people who are responsible for hiring don't even really know (let alone care) what precisely a grant is. So I suggest not to list Z at all. (By the way, the same goes for Y.)

@JochenGlueck, I concur.

Nonacademic doesn't mean they aren't involved in research, or aren't grant- and funds-seeking institutions. I would be more interested in knowing if they were responsible for seeking and securing those grants, and is there supporting evidence for that. Not having to teach that skill from scratch is a positive factor i would consider in hiring as a non academic.

I think it's reasonable to count for fellowships or similar, where money is for the student and the university only ever sees the money because that particular student is a student there.
If the money is to fund an arbitrary student, it's not specifically allocated to the individual and shouldn't be listed as a grant.
It probably doesn't matter nearly as much to an industry employer as skills and productivity, which means there's even less reason to try to manipulate the number with dodgy allocation.

I agree - if the student applied for and won a competitive fewllowship (NSF, Maxwell, ...), then that should be a line on the CV. Actual dollars are pretty irrelevant in any case.

@JonCuster Yeah, the actual dollars may even be somewhat counterproductive in an industry setting, where people are more used to seeing numbers in terms of overall business impact; if someone is only bringing in money equal to their own salary, they're typically going to be seen as a net drag on a company, whereas they are seen as self-sufficient in an academic context.

If they applied for, and was awarded, the funding for their PhD then they are at full liberty to state it. If someone else got the funding and they were then selected as the PhD student to work on the project, then no, they should not.
The difference is that they by putting it on their CV they would be taking credit for bringing in funding. If they did not, it is unethical.
